# problem with starting a thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, onresume

I have an activity in Android which displays as a background a picture.When I click on the background I use an `intent` to go at another activity....
Here is how my code looks like:

```
public class Precisari extends Activity{

    protected boolean _active = true;
    protected int _splashTime = 10000;
    public SplashThread  splashThread;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.precisari);

     splashThread=new SplashThread();

    }


    public class SplashThread extends Thread
    {
        public SplashThread()
        {

        }


        public void run() {

            try {

                int waited = 0;
                while (_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);
                    if (_active) {

                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
                //finish();
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), com.SplashScreen.ConnectWithFb.class);
                startActivity(i);
                stop();

            }
        }

    }



    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            _active=false;
            }
        return true;
    }


    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        _active=true;
        splashThread.start();
    }

    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        splashThread.stop();

    }


}
```

I'm using a thread which I started in `onResume()`...this thread loops until  boolean variabile `_active` is set to false .The variable is set to false when I click on the screen of the emulator:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                _active=false;
                }
            return true;
        }
```

and then I pass to the next activity by using an intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), com.SplashScreen.ConnectWithFb.class);
```

The thread is started in `onResume()`and stopped in `onPause()`.The idea is that when I come back to this activity I want the same idea to work....to pass to the next activity when I click the screen!

Here is how my logcat looks like:

```
 Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.SplashScreen/com.SplashScreen.Precisari}: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2950)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2965)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1889)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.               at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1322)
    at com.SplashScreen.Precisari.onResume(Precisari.java:101)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3763)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
```

Could please someone tell me what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: What?I don't understand!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

put sleep(100) in try catch block.

Comment: What is the connection with the fact that it says that my thread was already started?

Comment: Use another try catch to put only sleep()

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting that exception is because it is illegal to stop and restart a single Thread object instance. You're calling start/stop in onResume/onPause respectively, but you're never reallocating the thread object (from onCreate).

In order to stop and restart your thread, you need to reallocate the Thread object.

The Android source is fairly explicit in this regard:

```
// Thread.java, line ~178
/**
 * Reflects whether this Thread has already been started. A Thread
 * can only be started once (no recycling). Also, we need it to deduce
 * the proper Thread status.
 */
boolean hasBeenStarted = false;

// Thread.java, line ~1043
public synchronized void start()
{
    if (hasBeenStarted) {
        throw new IllegalThreadStateException("Thread already started."); // TODO Externalize?
    }

    hasBeenStarted = true;  // <--- Look here!

    VMThread.create(this, stackSize);
}
```

*hasBeenStarted* is never reset back to false - even when the thread exits.